# Thymeleaf: show text if the attribute and property exists

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

Is there a simple way in thymeleaf to show the content of an attribute property if the property and the attribute exist? If there's an attribute "error" with a property "summary" in my html page, I'd like to show it:

```
<span th:text="${error.summary}">error summary</span>
```

If there is no attribute "error" the following error is raised:

`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'summary' cannot be found on null`

Currently I'm using the following approach, which just seems too complicated.

```
<span th:if="${error != null and error.summary != null}"><span th:text="${error.summary}">error summary</span></span>
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve that?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Sure! Since the processor associated with the `th:if` attribute has a [higher precedence](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence) than the one associated with the `th:text` attribute, it will be evaluated first. Thus you can write:

```
<span th:if="${error != null && error.summary != null}" th:text="${error.summary}">Static summary</span>
```

You could even shorten it using:

```
<span th:text="${error?.summary}">Static summary</span>
```

But I think in this case, whether the summary exist or not, the span tag will be created, which is a bit ugly.

See more info about conditional expressions [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: Tanks.Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @tduchateau We can use `th:remove="tag"` if there is no need to have to `<span>` tag right?

Comment: The link to the conditional expressions is not working.