# Thymeleaf th:if with null error

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to populate a thymeleaf template with some data from Spring Boot.
What I'm trying to do is this

```
<tr th:if="${group.organization}">
    <td class="col_title"><b>Organization:</b></td>
    <td class="organization-field-content" th:text="${group.organization}"></td>
</tr>
```

I've tried both the solutions proposed here:
[Thymeleaf: show text if the attribute and property exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529085/thymeleaf-show-text-if-the-attribute-and-property-exists)
and, following the render order of thymeleaf, since the `group.organization` is null, the entire inner `td`s should not be displayed.

Still there a problem because Thymeleaf complains saying

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] 
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating 
SpringEL expression: "group.organization" (group)] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since the group object exists, just the organization is null

Comment: is `organization` a `boolean` property?  If not, it makes more sense to do:

`<tr th:if="${group != null && group.organization != null}">
    <td class="col_title"><b>Organization:</b></td>
    <td class="organization-field-content" th:text="${group.organization}"></td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 0):

You may confirm if really your group object is not null by just dumping it in a span something like `<span th:utext="${group}" />`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following to check whether group and organisation are not null before showing the div.

```
<tr th:if="${group != null && group.organization != null}">
    <td class="col_title"><b>Organization:</b></td>
    <td class="organization-field-content" th:text="${group.organization}"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies, turned out the problem was somewhere else in the end.

All the proposed solution were still giving the same problem, and that was because of a method inside the Group Spring-data Model.
Indeed the null pointer exception came out of the `getOrganization` method, which wasn't serializing correctly the `null` value.

Maybe this can help someone else in the future