# How to check object.field is not define in ThymeLeaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

check object.field is not exist

example:

```
StaffDTO {
    private int staffId;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

what I've tried (did not work)

```
<div th:text="${staffTest.?asdasd}">asdasd</div>
```

Comment: How about this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529085/thymeleaf-show-text-if-the-attribute-and-property-exists)

Comment: that's just a case of null checking, my case if the wrong field name of the object is written, templateParser will throw the error immediately. btw thks for share

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you wanna do

but if you want to get list of available properties try this on you object

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames();
```

Comment: I'm handling on html file with thymeleaf and spring boot framework, bro. so I can't use what u said. hmmm